# I used adb commands to set the trigger for led notification. But the trigger is reset after a reboot. Can I make this trigger permanent?

Tags: android, triggers, adb, led

Used this code:

```
echo battery-charging-blink-full-solid >/sys/class/leds/charging/trigger
```

but it sets back to default after reboot.

Comment: `sysfs` is not persistent by design. to make your changes stick - you need to change your device's init scripts to apply the settings on every boot

Comment: @AlexP. Would you know where I might find instructions to do that?